# Why use call in object prototypical methods?

Tags: javascript

when trying to see if an object `x` has a property called 'name' we do the below:

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'name');`

my question is why does doing it like:

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(x, 'name');`

doesn't work.

Comment: Because the `hasOwnProperty` method only accepts one argument? You are passing two in your non-working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the "call" method ties the first parameter as "this" to "hasOwnProperty". You can also leave out the "call", but then the syntax should be `x.hasOwnProperty('name')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call call `hasOwnProperty` on `Object.prototype` you'll have to specify the object you are talking about (= the value of this), so you use `call` to specify the value of `this` you want to associate with the function call.

Calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(x, 'name')` wouldn't make sense because `hasOwnProperty` only expects the name of the property as argument, you can't pass it the value of another object, and the object being called the function on will be ... the prototype of Object.

But you could also simply do this :

```js
x.hasOwnProperty("name")
```

Example :

```js
function MyObj(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const o = new MyObj("test");

console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, "name")); // true
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty("name")); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(o, "name")); // false
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("name")); // false
```